# HTML Post Request Parameters

Tags: javascript, ajax

Is there any way one can find out what the post request parameters are being sent to a website from Firefox ? I tried using HTTPFox plugin, though it shows the request is post, but I want to know the post parameters and their values.

Eg : http://www.farfetch.com/shopping/women/dresses-1/items.aspx#ps=2&pv=180&oby=5, when "next" is pressed what is the request call being made ?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/), in console tab you'll find your request and all information will get after click on it

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely get [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/).
It's a Firefox plugin that adds tons of utilities for web development.

Once it's installed, the button will appear on the navigation toolbar. Click on it, go into the Net tab and enable it.

You'll see the requests appearing in the panel as they are being made: just click on one of them and it will expand showing more details. If it is a POST request, it will have a sub-tab named "Post" that will show you the content of the request.